# ACRU4 model run error: climate file -> "Error running display and data rules"

Tags: hydrology, models

ACRU model was running fine and producing output.
After a few runs and parameter changes, the model returns this error message [image]
Not sure what went wrong or changed.

Does anyone know what this means or how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of two issues:

**Sometimes & likely:** You’ve run out of space on your computer (check your local drive for space)

**Often & very likely:** There is data in the climate file which is in the wrong place or has the wrong formatting (the solution is to recheck your climate files and run through it line by line for anything that is out of place, it’s easy to miss this in between several runs and updates to a climate file)